# Drop Down Menus Wrong Size and Dropping Down in wrong Direction

Tags: html, css

I have a mobile version of my website which I have added CSS to handle drop down menu's the problem I am running into is it drops down in the wrong location and is the wrong size. Being still fairly new to CSS, I am stumped on how to fix this. Any help?

This is the Website showing the example on the specials button
http://brianrobinsonenterprises.us/mobile.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>psdtowebbremobile.psd</title>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
    .dropdown {
     position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
       background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
       box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
       padding: 12px 16px;
       z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
        <div id="background">
            <div id="Layer0"><img src="images/Layer0.png"></div>
            <div id="Layer1"><img src="images/Layer1.png"></div>
            <div id="DVD"><img src="images/DVD.png"></div>

                <div class="dropdown"><div id="Specails"><span><img src="images/Specails.png"></div>
                 <div class="dropdown-content">
                 <p>Hello World!</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Categories"><img src="images/Categories.png"></div>
            <div id="Rectangle1"><img src="images/Rectangle1.png"></div>
            <div id="Shape1"><img src="images/Shape1.png"></div>
            <div id="DVDcopy"><img src="images/DVDcopy.png"></div>
            <div id="Specailscopy"><img src="images/Specailscopy.png"></div>
            <div id="Categoriescopy"><img src="images/Categoriescopy.png"></div>
        </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: try adding `.dropdown { z-index: 9; } .dropdown-content { top: 94px; }`

Comment: @Michael Coker Perfect! Thank You! That Worked Beautifully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `.dropdown` to appear above the other menus, so add a higher `z-index`. To put it over all of the other elements, use `.dropdown { z-index: 11; }` and then you need to put `.dropdown-content` below the `#Specials` element. `#Specials` is `top: 68px; height: 26px;` so add `.dropdown-content { top: 94px; }` (68 + 26 = 94)